# laravel join query is not working

Tags: laravel, join

I have the next query and I want to get the `price_types.name` but is not returned:

```
$projects = Project::with('projectsTask')
        ->select('projects.*',
            'price_types.name as name_type'
        )
        ->where('client_id', $client->id)
        ->join('price_types', 'tasks.type_list', '=', 'price_types.id')
        ->orderBy('id')
        ->get();
```

Here an image query is retrievng
[This on picture "type_list" must be string text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B9IA1.png)

Maybe somebody can help me.

Many thanks!

Comment: What do you want to achieve? type_list is an integer at your database?

Comment: Yes, "tasks.type_list" is an integer, and i wonna take "price_types.name" is a string :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$projects = Project::join('tasks', 'projects.id', '=', 'tasks.project_id')
        ->select('tasks.*',
            'price_types.name as name_type',
            'statuses.name as name_status'
        )
        ->where([['client_id', $client->id], ['tasks.status_type', '!=', 2]])
        ->join('price_types', 'tasks.type_list', '=', 'price_types.id')
        ->join('statuses', 'tasks.status_type', '=', 'statuses.type')
        ->orderBy('tasks.id', 'DESC')
        ->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 $projects = Project::with('projectsTask')
    ->where('client_id', $client->id)
    ->join('price_types', 'tasks.type_list', '=', 'price_types.id')
    ->orderBy('id')
    ->get([''projects.*',
        'price_types.name as name_type'']);
```

`get` method receive as parameter an array with fields that you want.

Comment: Sorry, it's not working (((

SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'tasks.type_list' in 'on clause' (SQL: select `projects`.*, `price_types`.`name` as `name_type` from `projects` inner join `price_types` on `tasks`.`type_list` = `price_types`.`id` where `client_id` = 1 order by `id` asc)

Comment: I done it's some another way. Thanks for you help! :)